# Phaser Putting sprites in and taking them out of an array

Tags: arrays, methods, phaser-framework

I'm trying to use an array of sprites as an inventory system, but to do so I need three methods to use with the array.

1. one that puts sprites in the array
2. one that shows if a certain sprite is in the array or not
3. one that takes the sprites out of the array

I have a solution for the second one, and I've tried a few times to use add and remove methods for the other two, but I don't know exactly how to call those methods correctly, as the ways I tried just got me error messages. As I have found the online documentation too confusing for me, can please tell me of the methods I'm looking for?

Also, I've tried creating the array in 2 formats:

```
let inventory = [];
```

and

```
let inventory = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
```

Do the methods I'm looking for change depending on which one I use.

If it helps, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode, employing arcade physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the `push` and `splice` methods of the array.

**Add Sprite to Array:**

```
const array = []

const sprite = [REFERENCE TO SPRITE]
array.push(sprite)
```

**Remove Sprite from Array:**

```
const array = []

const sprite = [REFERENCE TO SPRITE]
array.splice(array.indexOf(sprite))
```

Comment: @EmptyStone No problem, do you mind marking my answer as correct?